# Lucene.Net.Index.MergePolicy+MergeException exception in Lucene.net

Tags: lucene.net

```
I am using Lucene.net , while indexing I got following exception
```

Application: SysToolsBatchIndexer.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: Lucene.Net.Index.MergePolicy+MergeException
Stack:
   at Lucene.Net.Index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.HandleMergeException(System.Exception)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler+MergeThread.Run()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Can any one tell me the exact cause of the exception ?

Comment: Do you remember if you ever fixed the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The exception contains an error-message which describes the problem in more detail. Make sure you log that message in your program.

One typical situation where this exception occur is when the disk runs out of space. When segments of the index are merged additional disk space is required.

Comment: This is an old issue but we are experiencing a similar error on Umbraco 7.60, 7.15.1 & 7.15.3 (site was gradually upgraded). I've described the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59725408/unhandled-exception-in-appdomain-read-past-eof-error-in-lucene-indexing @DanielBrixen