# Unhandled exception in AppDomain - read past EOF error in Lucene indexing

Tags: iis, lucene, umbraco, umbraco7, examine

We've been having a problem with Lucene indexing for a while already.

Basically quite often when we try to publish a content the indexing just throws an error like this:

```
2020-01-13 22:22:38,068 [P36840/D2/TLucene Merge Thread #0] ERROR Umbraco.Core.UmbracoApplicationBase - Unhandled exception in AppDomain (terminating)
Lucene.Net.Index.MergePolicy+MergeException: Exception of type 'Lucene.Net.Index.MergePolicy+MergeException' was thrown. ---> System.IO.IOException: read past EOF
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.HandleMergeException(Exception t, OneMerge merge)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.Merge(OneMerge merge)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.DoMerge(OneMerge merge)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.MergeThread.Run()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Lucene.Net.Index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.HandleMergeException(Exception exc)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.MergeThread.Run()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

We get `Secure Connection Failed` on the public site as the result, the content is being saved but not included in cache so it does not display on the website.

Then we are unable to access Examine Management dashboard to restart indexes.

The error sometime slooks like this too:

```
 2019-12-30 14:49:14,895 [P18524/D2/T28] ERROR Umbraco.Core.UmbracoApplicationBase - Unhandled exception in AppDomain (terminating)
System.IO.IOException: Cannot overwrite: D:\Inetpub\vhosts\mysite.com\httpdocs\App_Data\TEMP\ExamineIndexes\Internal\Index\_pe.cfs
   at Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory.InitOutput(String name)
   at Lucene.Net.Store.SimpleFSDirectory.CreateOutput(String name)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.CompoundFileWriter.Close()
   at Lucene.Net.Index.DocumentsWriter.CreateCompoundFile(String segment)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.DoFlushInternal(Boolean flushDocStores, Boolean flushDeletes)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.DoFlush(Boolean flushDocStores, Boolean flushDeletes)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.PrepareCommit(IDictionary`2 commitUserData, Boolean internal_Renamed)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.Commit(IDictionary`2 commitUserData)
   at Examine.LuceneEngine.Providers.LuceneIndexer.IndexCommiter.TimerRelease() in C:\projects\examine-qvx04\src\Examine\LuceneEngine\Providers\LuceneIndexer.cs:line 1711
   at Examine.LuceneEngine.Providers.LuceneIndexer.IndexCommiter.<ScheduleCommit>b__7_0(Object _) in C:\projects\examine-qvx04\src\Examine\LuceneEngine\Providers\LuceneIndexer.cs:line 1663
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
```

In such case publishing a content becomes practically ineffective.

Any idea what's the cause? And how to fix it? I can see the index becomes corrupted but why?

I have checked several similar issues like these:

[Umbraco Indexing Error Filling Up Logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468541/umbraco-indexing-error-filling-up-logs)

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENENET-527 but none of them is our case - I can't see any 0kB segment files.

**EDIT**

The error crashes the whole website causing Secure Connection Failed error and it happens when trying to perform a save on a content (no matter via CMS or the front site).

Comment: Anyone can help with it?

Comment: No suggestions?

Comment: I don't know how umbraco handles commit and optimize, but it seems on every commit it also optimizing the indexes (merging index files, removing docs marked as deleted etc.) this operation heavily depends on IO operations of the operating system and it's filesystem, there seems IO operations are not being handled correctly. If possible can you try NOT to optimize/merge after every commit but only periodically? (e.g. optimize every 2h, if your site slows down, decrease the period)

Comment: @mow unfortunately we do not generally have that level of control, on a save/delete/publish it updates the indexes affected.

But the weird part is it often works for a while.

The bit that got me was the 'read past eof' error